# 22.04 Server LTS installer does not detect wifi connections

Tags: server, system-installation, 22.04

I am trying to install 22.04 LTS Server on my late 2012 mac mini machine.
The installer does not detect my wifi connection options and the machine is not connected via eth.

My newer PC did not have this issue and I was able to run server installation using the wifi connection.

Can you please advise on what could be causing this and on how to proceed?

spci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 commend outputs nothing.

Netplan yaml file:

```
ethernets:
    zz-all-en:
        dhcp4: true
        match:
            name: en*
    zz-all-eth:
         dhcp4: true
         match:
             name: eth*
 version: 2
```

output of ls /sys/class/net

```
enp1s0f0  lo
```

lsusb:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cm4S.jpg)
Thank you.

Comment: An unsupported or unrecognized WiFi device in the MAC. The PC would not be using the same WiFi device.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 just updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: "spci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 commend outputs nothing." It is `lspci` and not `spci` Please try again. Also add: `lsusb`

Comment: @chili555 sorry I mean "lspci" and it finds (grep part) nothing. adding lsusb shortly

Comment: Let's dig a bit deeper: `sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.
I had this same issue on my Raspberry Pi.

Reboot, when the installer starts, breakout into a live session by pressing Alt+F2. You will now be presented with a shell, run:

```bash
nmcli d wifi connect ssid $YOUR_SSID password $YOUR_PASSWORD
```

and the you should be able to connect with WiFi.

Now run Alt+F1 to return to the installer.

Have a great day,
Android776

Comment: Thank you @Android776 - the only problem is that "nmcli" command is not found. Without the internet connections I was not able to install network-manager.

Comment: Dang! That's really frustrating. I really don't have any idea about what another solution could be, but I really hope you can find a solution to this problem.